# Given $|f'(x)|\leq r<1$ show that $f(x)=x$ is unique solution

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Suppose that $|f'(x)|\leq r<1, \forall x\in R$. How do I show that the equation $f(x)=x$ has a unique solution?

Comment: I assume that the equation has two solution, say p and q.

Comment: I think Lagrange's Mean Value Theorem is useful here.

Comment: You need to show that a solution exists and that it is unique. Contraction mapping theorem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First we need to show a solution exists:

Let $\phi(x) = f(x)-x$. If $\phi(0) = 0$ we are finished.

Suppose $\phi(0) >0$. Note that $\phi'(x) = f'(x)-1 \le r-1 < 0$. Then the
mean value theorem gives
$\phi(x) = \phi(0) + \phi'(\xi) x \le\phi(0) + (r-1) x$ and a
quick computation shows that $\phi({ \phi(0) \over -(r-1) }) \le 0$, hence
the intermediate value theorem shows that there is some $x$ such that $\phi(x) =0$, or $f(x) = x$.

If $\phi(0) <0$ a similar analysis applies.

Hence there is some $x$ such that $f(x) = x$.

Next we need to show that the solution is unique.

Suppose $y<x$.
We have $\phi(x) = \phi(y)+ \phi'(\xi)(x-y)$ and so
$\phi(x)-\phi(y) =\phi'(\xi)(x-y) \le (r-1)(x-y) <0$. Hence
if $\phi(x)=\phi(y)$, we must have $x=y$. Hence any zero of $\phi$ is unique.

Comment: Pls Copper.hat could you shade more light on 'a quick computation' Thanks

Comment: Well, you have $\phi(x) \le \phi(0) + (r-1)x$ for all $x \ge 0$, so you can see that the right hand side will be $\le 0$ for some value of $x$. Solve $\phi(0) + (r-1)x = 0$ and then you know that $\phi(x) \le 0$. Solving gives $x = { \phi(0) \over -(r-1) }$.

Comment: Pls. where do you get this $\xi$?

Comment: The mean value theorem.

Comment: Means that $\xi\in(x,0)$ or $\xi\in(x,y)$?

Comment: Why the downvote?